# How can I label a table of histograms with the names of the data symbols, not the data themselves?

Tags: plotting, labeling, histograms, symbols

How can I label a table of histograms with the names of the data symbols, not the data themselves?

If I want to make a table of plots with each plot labeled with the name of the function it plots, this is simple:

```
f[x_] := x; g[x_] := x^2;
Table[Plot[p[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> p], {p, {f, g}}]
```

However, if I want to do the same for `Histogram`, I have not figured out how. I have tried various combinations using `ToString`, `Hold`, `HoldForm`, and `Unevaluated`, as well as `ChartLabels`. For example,

```
l = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20]; m = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20];
Table[Histogram[p, PlotLabel -> p], {p, {l, m}}]
```

does not work, as the labels are the values of `l` and `m`, not the strings `l` and `m`.

The same question applies to the format analogous to

```
Plot[#[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {f, g}
```

which works for `Plot` but not for `Histogram`.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in your first example, `f` doesn't evaluate to anything, only `f[x]` does. For your second example however, `l` is already evaluated to the list of values.

There are various ways to go about this, here are some:

```
l = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20]; m = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20];

Table[Histogram[ReleaseHold@p, PlotLabel -> p], {p, {HoldForm[l], HoldForm[m]}}]
Histogram[ReleaseHold@#, PlotLabel -> HoldForm@#] & /@ Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@{l, m}
Function[, Histogram[ReleaseHold@#, PlotLabel -> HoldForm@#], HoldFirst] /@ Unevaluated@{l, m}
KeyValueMap[Histogram[#2, PlotLabel -> #] &, <|"l" -> l, "m" -> m|>]

l2[] = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20]; m2[] = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20];
Table[Histogram[p[], PlotLabel -> p], {p, {l2, m2}}]
```

[image]

The first three solutions show various ways of preventing premature evaluation of `l` and `m`. The fourth solution shows how you can use the keys of an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) as labels for the plots. Finally, the last solution shows how to imitate the behavior of your first example

Comment: Maybe obvious from context, but `l2` and `m2` in your fourth method are undefined.  Also, a more verbose answer using #4 is exactly what I was typing up when you answered :).

Comment: @NonDairyNeutrino Thanks! I completely forgot to copy that line...